# cast datasource to object

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

i have class

```
public class CLASS_K
{
    public static List<AA> simpleList = new List<AA>()
    {
        new AA(){NNN = "o1", NNN2 = "o1a"},
        new AA(){NNN = "o2", NNN2 = "o2a"}
    };

    public class AA
    {
        public string NNN { get; set; }
        public string NNN2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I set binding for label :

```
label1.DataBindings.Add("text", CLASS_K.simpleList[1], "NNN");
```

How cast dataSource from label to class AA ?

My wrong idea:

```
BindingSource binding = (BindingSource)label1.DataBindings[0].DataSource;
CLASS_K.AA b = (CLASS_K.AA) binding.DataSource;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataSource` contains object of type `CLASS_K.AA`, so try this:

```
if (label1.DataBindings.Count != 0)
{
    var b = label1.DataBindings[0].DataSource as CLASS_K.AA;
    if (b != null)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is null

Comment: Do I have to set the type of DataBindings ?

Comment: @De.yw what is the result of following code: `foreach (Binding item in label1.DataBindings) {              Debug.WriteLine(item.DataSource.GetType().FullName);}` ?

Comment: WindowsFormsApplication5.CLASS_K+AA

Comment: @De.yw so everything is ok, b can't be null. Try debug this code.

Comment: I set  also WindowsFormsApplication5.CLASS_K+AA in DataBindings -> Text in design mode.. Here was the problem. Thank You.